# Error message wont show on page

Tags: php

If a user is trying to log in with an account thats not confirmed or if the password is incorrect it'll come up with a little error box to tell them when the page reloads.

When the login script is run and I try to log into an account that isn't confirmed yet I return it with this url

signin.php?error=no_confirm

When the page reloads however it has the correct url but nothing happens! Do I have the code below set up correctly?

```
<?php
$error = $_GET['error'];

echo $error;

 if ($error) {
 if($error == 'mismatch') {
    echo "
<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> You need to confirm your account before you sign 
in!
</div>
";
} elseif ($error == 'no_confirm') {
echo "
<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Youre username or password was incorrect.
</div>
";
} else {
echo "";
}
 } else {
    echo "nov";
 }

?>
```

Comment: Does it print `nov` then?

Comment: nope it prints nothing and i just tested to see if its printing nothing bc of the empty echo but its not even printing that so thats why im confused

Comment: [Turn on your PHP errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display) then.

Comment: Maybe a typo in your url?

Comment: and try var_dump($_GET);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `if ($error) { }` and change it to `if(isset($error)) { }`

And make sure that your GET request is right:

```
.php?error=mismatch
```

Comment: I did that but it gave the same result as before... nothing :(

Comment: Hey I just tried to do a basic <?php echo "Hello World"; ?> on my page below the error display php code and its not outputing anything what would be the cause of this? Also var_dump doesn't work or anything else im confused about this

Comment: Try to output all errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: Its already enabled its just ignoring the php tags but the ones at the top and bottom for the include header.php and footer.php all work as well as the script for the form

Comment: Put the error reporting on those pages too, might be a typo on those pages or maybe a more serious error that is causing your page to fail

Comment: OMG IM DUM literally had the php on the wrong page i edited i had it on the registration page not the login page!

Comment: Heres a check for helping me anyway XD

Answer (score 0):

Ok you don't set your page in utf-8 and it is just like a text file try to save it again

Comment: No I want to help you I see your comment to another answer when you said that it display the code instead of the result of not all your page do that why this page only do it ask yourself this question

Comment: You'll need to add this to your server configuration:

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
that is assuming you have installed php properly, which may not be the case since it doesn't work where it normally would immediately after installing.

It is entirely possible that you'll also have to add the php so/dll to your apache config using a LoadModule directive (usually in httpd.conf)

Answer (score 0):

Hello your code is working for me, but also i wrote alternative way for you, you can try that way :

```
<?php
$error = $_GET['error'];

echo $error;


if (preg_match('/mismatch/',$error))
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> You need to confirm your account before you sign 
in!
</div>";
}

if (preg_match('/no_confirm/',$error))
{
    echo "<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>
  <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Youre username or password was incorrect.
</div>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a double " instead of single '
    $error = $_GET["error"];

Comment: No difference here.

Comment: Ok does echo $error in second line display something ?